# Making a np.einsum faster when inputs are many identical arrays? (Or any other faster method)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have a piece of code of type:

```
nnt = np.real(np.einsum('xa,xb,yc,yd,abcde->exy',evec,evec,evec,evec,quartic))
```

where `evec` is (say) an L x L `np.float32` array, and `quartic` is a L x L x L x L x T `np.complex64` array.

I found that this routine is rather slow.

I thought that since all the `evec`'s are identical, there might be a faster way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For start you can reuse the first calculation:

```
evec2 = np.real(np.einsum('xa,xb->xab',evec,evec))
nnt = np.real(np.einsum('xab,ycd,abcde->exy',evec2,evec2,quartic))
```

And if you don't care about memory and only need performance:

```
evec2 = np.real(np.einsum('xa,xb->xab',evec,evec))
nnt = np.real(np.einsum('xab,ycd,abcde->exy',evec2,evec2,quartic,optimize=True))
```

Comment: Good idea there. To get max perf, think you can skip `optimize` for `evec2`, as there's no sum reduction there.

Comment: @Divakar, That is true. Thank you for the point. I edit the post.

Comment: Wow! It's blazing fast. It went from 16 seconds to 0.007 seconds. I'll make sure to try to reuse calculations from now on. Thanks!